# How to store a non self enclosing tag inside a variable and call it in the render() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have the following:

```
<Col xs={6} md={2}>
    <Card someProp={myProp} />
</Col>
```

`<Col></Col>` is a grid component. I want to set the props on it differently based on the value of a variable. If it was a self enclosing tag I would simply store it in a variable like so and call that in the render method:

```
let someVar = <Col xs={6} md={2} />

if(someCondition) {
    someVar = <Col xs={12} md={6} />
}

{someVar} // Called like so...
```

But it's not a self enclosing tag and doing this causes an error:

```
let someVar = <Col xs={6} md={2}>

if(someCondition) {
    someVar = <Col xs={12} md={6}>
}

{someVar}
    <Card someProp={myProp} />
</Col>
```

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a component, pass `children` and propagate it to the actual child (warning: `someVar` **should** be capitalized):

```
let SomeVar = ({children}) => <Col xs={6} md={2}>{children}</Col>

if(someCondition) {
    SomeVar = ({children}) => <Col xs={12} md={6}>{children}</Col>
}

<SomeVar>
    <Card someProp={myProp} />
</SomeVar>
```

Or :

```
let SomeVar = ({children}) => {
    if(someCondition) {
        return <Col xs={6} md={2}>{children}</Col>
    }
    else {
        return <Col xs={12} md={6}>{children}</Col>
    }
}

<SomeVar>
    <Card someProp={myProp} />
</SomeVar>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Col xs={someCondition ? 6 : 12} md={someCondition ? 2 : 6}>
    <Card someProp={myProp} />
</Col>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the `if...else` logic define the `props` only, not the entire component like so:

```
let colProps = someCondition ? { xs: 6, md: 2 } : { xs: 12, md: 6 };

<Col {...colProps}>
    <Card someProp={myProp} />
</Col>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is rather badly phrased, but what OP is looking for is replacing the `Col` component itself, see the last 3 lines of code on the question.